# Развернуть результат выборки суммируя и группируя(по условию) значения по годам

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица:

```
rid  obj  date                     summa
209  500  2018-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  404  2018-01-01 00:00:00.000  10,00
209  404  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  500  2019-01-01 00:00:00.000  20,50
209  404  2020-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  500  2020-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  404  2021-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  500  2021-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  404  2022-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  500  2022-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  404  2023-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  500  2023-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  404  2024-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
209  500  2024-01-01 00:00:00.000  0,00
```

Необходимо ее развернуть так, чтобы получить результат в виде:

Текущий год = 2018

```
rid  obj  current_year  first_year  second_year subsequent_years
209  404  0,00          0,00        0,00        0,00
209  500  20,50         0,00        0,00        0,00
```

или

Текущий год = 2019

```
rid  obj  current_year  first_year  second_year subsequent_years
209  404  10,00         0,00        0,00        0,00
209  500  0,00          20,50       0,00        0,00
```

**current_year** - Только суммы **текущего заданного года**
**first_year** - Только суммы **current_year + 1**
**second_year** - Только суммы **current_year + 2**
**subsequent_years** - Суммы **всех последующих**

То есть если задать текущим годом 2010, то результат будет в виде:

Текущий год = 2010

```
rid  obj  current_year  first_year  second_year subsequent_years
209  404  0,00          0,00        0,00        10,00
209  500  0,00          0,00        0,00        20,50
```

У меня получилось нечто следующее, но не думаю, что это лучший вариант. Возможно кто-то знает способ более оптимально построить запрос?

```
declare @cur_year int = 2010

select [rid] = [sy].[rid]
     , [obj] = [sy].[obj]
     , sum(case [sy].[year] when @cur_year then [sy].[summa] else 0 end) as [current_year]
     , sum(case [sy].[year] when @cur_year + 1 then [sy].[summa] else 0 end) as [first_year]
     , sum(case [sy].[year] when @cur_year + 2 then [sy].[summa] else 0 end) as [second_year]
     , sum(case [sy].[year] when 0 then [sy].[summa] else 0 end) as [subsequent_years]
from ( select [r].[rid]
            , [r].[obj]
            , year([r].[date]) as [year]
            , [r].[summa]
       from [dbo].[rods] as [r]
       where 1 = 1
             and year([r].[date]) between @cur_year and @cur_year + 2
       union
       select [r].[rid]
            , [r].[obj]
            , 0
            , sum([r].[summa]) as [summa]
       from [dbo].[rods] as [r]
       where 1 = 1
             and @cur_year + 2 < year([r].[date])
       group by [r].[rid]
              , [r].[obj] ) as [sy]
group by [sy].[rid]
       , [sy].[obj]
```

Comment: Всё нормально... кроме того, что во FROM достаточно использовать исходную таблицу напрямую - все эти подзапросные навороты не имеют вообще никакого смысла.

Comment: @Akina дак в подзапрос юнион спрятан

Comment: хотя, да. в самом этом юнионе и замены последующих годов на 0 смысла нет.

Comment: возможно, автор не знает. что можно писать `case when y > @curYear + 2 then ....` ? То есть, что в `when` может стоять выражение, а не константа?